# Kannel routing based on prefix

Tags: kannel

I've got a trouble with Kannel. I am using it as an SMS aggregator like this ESME-Kannel-SMSC. I've got several SMSC and I need to implement routing based on phone number prefix. Is it possible? Anyone has done it before?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Kannel documentation](http://kannel.org/download/1.4.4/userguide-1.4.4/userguide.html) for SMS center variables:

`allowed-prefix`: A list of phone number prefixes which are accepted to be sent through this SMSC. Multiple entries are separated with semicolon (';'). For example, "040;050" prevents sending of any SMS message with prefix of 040 or 050 through this SMSC. If denied-prefix is unset, only these numbers are allowed. If set, number are allowed if present in allowed or not in denied list.

`denied-prefix`: A list of phone number prefixes which are NOT accepted to be sent through this SMSC.

`preferred-prefix`: As denied-prefix, but SMS messages with receiver starting with any of these prefixes are preferably sent through this SMSC. In a case of multiple preferences, one is selected at random (also if there are preferences, SMSC is selected randomly)

Comment: I've tried this already, but it didn't help. These settings do no affect on the kannel routing behaviour..